# Replace dash character in Java String

Tags: java, string, replace, str-replace

I tried to replace "-" character in a Java String but is doesn't work :

```
str.replace("\u2014", "");
```

Could you help me ?

Comment: str = str.replace("\u2014", "");

Answer (score 11, accepted):

String is Immutable in Java. You have to reassign it to get the result back:

```
String str ="your string with dashesh";
str= str.replace("\u2014", "");
```

See the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) for details.

Answer (score 5):

this simply works..

```
    String str = "String-with-dash-";
    str=str.replace("-", "");
    System.out.println(str);
```

output - Stringwithdash

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy. You can use an Apache library, that will be useful while you develop an application.  This is apache-commons-lang. You can do the following:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String test = "Dash - string";
        String withoutDash = StringUtils.replace(test, "-", "");
        System.out.println(withoutDash);
    }

}
```

Comment: the apache commons lang library is a bit overkill to replace a dash in a string, java manages fine on its own

Comment: Yes, but did you see my comment ? "that will be useful while you develop an application" That's why I proposed this solution